# Call an external program to run as standard user from a requiredAdministrator program

Tags: vb.net, autoit, invoke, elevated-privileges

My Visual Basic program will copy files to a program files folder, so I have to use `requiredAdministrator` privileges since `asInvoker` won't allow to write in the program files folder.

After I copy the files I invoke an AutoIt script automating setup of files within the external program (for that the script calls the external program to start automation). The program that creates and copies the files to the "end" program functions fine. The script that calls the "end" program and does the automatic setup also works.

When I combine the 2 the "end" program (which I didn't write nor have the source code of) behaves erratically when run as admin (doesn't read the database or the needed files return an error and terminates itself). So run as admin is not an option. But since my program has to run as admin it looks like it passes the sames privileges to the AutoIt script which calls the "end" program as admin as well. It also happens if I call the "end" program from my app instead of the AutoIt script.

Is there any way to demote my app from admin to standard user after it copies the files, right before it calls either the AutoIt script or the "end" program so that the "end" program is not run as admin or a parameter that specifically makes the app to call the external program as standard user?

I'm using `Process.start("autoitscript.exe")` to call it. Or any other workaround that doesn't involve the AutoIt script calling the "end" program and my app because that works but not as I intent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky task to perform, but how about this:

1. Have your application start `asInvoker`, don't show any windows, and make check if it runs with elevated privileges using this code:

   ```
   Public Shared Function IsAdministrator() As Boolean
       Return (New WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
   End Function
   ```

   If it's not running with elevated privileges make it start an invisible `cmd` instance where you redirect the standard input.
2. Get the cmd process's PID and now start a new instance of your application with elevated privileges (can be done by setting `StartInfo.Verb = "runas"`) and pass the PID as a command-line parameter.
3. Now your new instance of the app starts and `IsAdministrator()` should return `True`.

   So now that you know that your app has administrator privileges you can check if the app has a command-line parameter that is parsable to an Integer. If so, store that Integer somewhere and then do all your admin-required work.
4. In the end where you want to start the `autoitscript.exe` application you create a process variable and assigns `Process.GetProcessById(<your PID Integer here>)` to it.

   For example:

   ```
   Dim cmdProcess As Process = Process.GetProcessById(cmdPID)
   ```
5. Now that you have control over the cmd instance again you just have to write to it's standard input ([this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18577/How-to-redirect-Standard-Input-Output-of-an-applic) describes a little how it works).

   You want to write two lines. The first is to start the other application:

   ```
   autoitscript.exe
   ```

   and the second is to close the cmd instance:

   ```
   exit
   ```

If anything's unclear just let me know.